# Alguem me ajuda nessa questão?

Tags: c, algoritmo

5) Faça um programa que receba o salário base de um funcionário, calcule e mostre seu salário a receber, sabendo-se que o funcionário tem gratificação de R$ 50 e paga imposto de 10%

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
float sal,imposto,s_final;
printf(" CALCULO DE SALARIO \n \n");

printf("Digite seu salario: ");
scanf("%f",&sal);

imposto= sal/100 * 0.1;
s_final = sal-imposto+50;

printf("Salario a receber: %f reais \n",&s_final);
printf("Valor dos impostos: %f reais",&sal);
return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Meu C está bem enferrujado mas eu acho que nos dois últimos `printf()` não é preciso usar `&`. P.S.: Se a única ajuda que você quer é para fazer as variáveis serem impressas corretamente, edite a pergunta e faça esse esclarecimento, senão do jeito que está pode ser considerada não clara o suficiente ("alguém me ajuda com isso").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O & (e comercial) serve para passar o endereço de uma variável, ou seja, quando você faz :
printf("Salario a receber: %f reais \n",&s_final);
printf("Valor dos impostos: %f reais",&sal);

a função printf está esperando um float, pois na string tem "%f", porém "&s_final" representa o endereço que o valor da variável "s_final" está armazenado.

Para corrigir isto, basta remover o & nas chamadas da função printf.

Comment: Depois de um tempo eu percebi o erro mesmo, brigadão cara

Answer (score 1):

Olá estava visualizando seu código e a lógica está correta, porém, você esqueceu que o "&" só é utilizado para scanf e não para printf (se usar para print irá pegar o endereço da memória e não o conteúdo).

Formulei novamente o código:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
 float sal,imposto,s_final;
 printf(" CALCULO DE SALARIO \n \n");
 printf("Digite seu salario: ");
 scanf("%f",&sal);

 imposto= (sal*10)/100;
 s_final = sal-imposto+50;

 printf("Salario a receber: %f reais \n",s_final);
 printf("Valor dos impostos: %f reais",sal);

 }
```

Espero te-lo ajudado!

Comment: Cara muito obrigado,eu tô iniciando agora a matéria de algoritmos na facul é ainda tô meio perdido kk vlw msm